# PDF on iOS Mobile Devices rending PDF as Image

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, pdf, png

I can't seem to figure out why I am having issues with an embedded PDF in a simple HTML page on ONLY iOS devices (iPad/iPhone).  Android and PC are fine.  On iOS devices it renders the PDF on the page as what appears to be a PNG file.  It only renders the first page of the PDF.  Scrolling doesn't work, neither does tap and hold. The browser doesn't see it as a PDF.  I've tried:

```
<object data='edoc.pdf' 
    type='application/pdf' 
    width='100%' 
    height='700px'>
</object>
```

Even tried an iFrame/DIV and while I can get the frame to scroll, it's only when I shrink the frame smaller than the "pdf" is renderd and it simply scrolls the single image around.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .scroll-wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .scroll-wrapper, .scroll-wrapper  {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
    }
</style>

<div class="scroll-wrapper">
<iframe src="edoc.pdf" id="test" ></iframe>
</div>
```

I'm at a loss.  My application needs to use an embedded PDF but I need to figure out why the iOS devices are such a hassle.  This behavior has been repeated on Safari, Chrome, Firefox.  On iPhone and iPad.  Version has been consistently iOS 10+.  I've checked the web server mime type is setup properly for PDF.  I've tried multiple PDF's from multiple locations.

Linking to the PDF

```
<a href='edoc.pdf'>PDF Name</a>
```

Works just fine. I'm lost. Help.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Use PDF.js to display the PDF instead. You won't get consistent behavior across all devices and operating systems when you rely on the Object tag.